# When changing an Azure B2C email adress, do I need to change the UPN as well

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure B2C with the GraphAPI I can change the email address of an existing user with a http PATCH command:
https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/

```
"SignInNames": [
{
  "type": "emailAddress",
  "value": "demo@domain.com"
}
```

This works, and I can login with the new email address.

But this leaves the `UPN` at the old value, do I need to set the `UPN` as well, or is there no harm in having the `UPN` stay at the old email address?

Comment: "SignInNames" should be "signInNames"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is no need to update the UPN field.

Answer (score 1):

Using v1.0 version of Microsoft Graph API, the body of the PATCH request to change the SignIn email address should be as following:

```
      {"identities":[{
        "signInType":"emailAddress",
        "issuer":"yourTenantName.onmicrosoft.com",
        "issuerAssignedId":"newemail@email.com"
      }]}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this, how did you get the new emails verified?

Answer (score -1):

That is why (in my opinion) email address should never be the default.  Instead choose username account option and email becomes a much easier field to deal with.