# Azure AD B2C: Change Local Email

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have two requirements that seem to conflict:

1. Use the email as the username.
2. Allow users to change their email.

The problem: if you configure the directory to use the email as the username then the edit profile policy does NOT show the email to allow you to change it.

Any solution I think of is a kludge and involves creating a whole new local account for the user.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: When a user changes their email, should their username change too?

Comment: Yes. In this case the username IS the email.

Comment: @dstrockis I've been working this pretty hard.  If you set up B2C local as `username`, I cannot find any way to change the email at all.  The mail field throws a read only exception when I make a graph call.  The policy flow for recover password also let's you specify whatever email you like, and it actually sends an email there, but then won't let you in.  If you forget your email, you're in real trouble.

Comment: @Pytry The server side B2C local registration page will not let you put in an email address if the local provider is set up as username.  No '.' and no '@' characters.

Comment: @Pytry I just successfully changed the login email on a B2C tenant using the graph api.  It's just not handled in the flow, so it might not do you much good.  FYI.

Comment: @nhwilly That was what we ended up having to do as well. I spoke with MS representatives, and they said that changing your email would be a future enhancement that they are working on. No ETA on it though.

Comment: According to the [answer, you can Change user name using custom policy in Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736947/change-user-name-using-custom-policy-in-azure-ad-b2c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the Azure AD Graph API to update the 'User' entity.

Comment: The reason I don't like that is that it leaves multifactor authentication and email verification up to us.. Which kind of ruins the reason for using B2C in the first place.

Comment: Yep, it's not ideal - AD B2C is certainly lacking in a few places considering the target market and still feels rather 'preview' in its current state.

Comment: I tried just that and it threw an exception that the 'mail' item was read only.

Comment: you can use the Graph to update an otherMail field which appears in B2C as Alternate email.  However, when you reset the password, that email address is not listed as an option.

Comment: Try this one [When changing an Azure B2C email adress, do I need to change the UPN as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645576/when-changing-an-azure-b2c-email-adress-do-i-need-to-change-the-upn-as-well)

Comment: While it isn't what I want, this is currently the only way to change the email when it is the username.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this via Microsoft Graph now too.
Example:

```
PATCH: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UUID}
{
    "identities": [
        {
            "signInType": "emailAddress",
            "issuer": "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
            "issuerAssignedId": "{new email address}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The possibilities have changed and @pswillies answer is not true anymore.
It is possible to change the sign-in name of local accounts where the sign-in name is an email address.

**See this official sample: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/change-sign-in-name**

It is using custom policies.