# Change user name using custom policy in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm using `username` in custom policies for authentication, either email or phone can be used as user name: `signInNames.emailAddress` or `signInNames.phoneNumber`. Now i need to enable profile edit, there user change the email and phone.
Problem i'm getting here is it saying the user already exist. Does B2C allows to change the user name or is there anything wrong in this profile?

Here is the technical profile to update profile:

```xml
                    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId">
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
                        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>
                        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
                    </InputClaims>
                    <PersistedClaims>
                        <!-- Required claims -->
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.phoneNumber"  />

                        <!-- Optional claims -->
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />

                    </PersistedClaims>
                    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
                </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it and I can change the user name successfully.

You can refer to [Use the new extension property or custom attribute in a user journey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom#use-the-new-extension-property-or-custom-attribute-in-a-user-journey) to configure it. Just ignore the step 3 because it's not a custom attribute.

When I change the currently username to an exist username, it will show:

> A user with the specified ID already exists. Please choose a different
>   one.

So make sure the username you want to modify to does not exist in the tenant.

Comment: Yes, that worked for me too. But initially from B2C i got the error message, later after couple of hours that worked without changing anything. Thanks

Comment: @Alex Glad to hear that. If my answer is helpful, you can accept it as answer then this issue will be closed. Thank you.