# B2C custom policy: How on sign up screen implement a link to sign in screen?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I was running a sample:
[Dynamic sign up or sign in Live demo](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/dynamic-sign-up-sign-in#live-demo)

When I executed test 3” In the sign-up or sign-in page select the Sign-up now link. Azure Azure AD B2C will take you to the sign-up page where you provide and verify your email address.”
and specified already registered email, I receive a message

> “A user with the specified ID already exists. Please choose a
> different one.”

Based on sample description “allows dynamically detecting whether a user can sign in or sign up” I expected to see message like
“You are already registered. Please **Sign-in** instead” and **Sign-in** link would redirect to sign-in page.

How to implement  a link to sign in screen on sign up screen  ?

Related question [B2C A sample of policy to perform a switch from a sign-up flow to a sign-in flow for existing user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76520952/b2c-a-sample-of-policy-to-perform-a-switch-from-a-sign-up-flow-to-a-sign-in-flow)

Btw: When in [Live demo](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/dynamic-sign-up-sign-in#live-demo)  I clicked cancel(On the top left corner). I’ve got

> Error: access_denied AADB2C90091: The user has cancelled entering
> self-asserted information. Correlation ID:
> fd895018-41ea-418c-9229-5f23501d727d Timestamp: 2023-06-21 20:34:33Z

I expected to go to initial sign-in page. Does Cancel button works on demo samples?

Comment: This thread should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736947/change-user-name-using-custom-policy-in-azure-ad-b2c
As far as the cancel function, this is expected behavior. The sample just doesn't have it connected to anything.