# Can we change email address of user from "Profile editing policies" in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-ad-b2c, azureportal

I am working on a project where we use Azure B2C authentication. We have to sign in, sign up, change user email address and password. I don't see email address field inside profile attribute in **Profile editing policies**. Can we change email address of user from "Profile editing policies" in Azure AD B2C? I am trying not to use Graph API for this.
For change password, sign-in and sign-up, I am redirecting to the url that comes after running the corresponding policies in portal. Is that the right approach?

Comment: It is not currently supported.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, **it is not possible to edit a user's email address** in Azure AD B2C, neither through any of the out of the box policies nor through the Graph API.

If this is something you'd like to see this you can request it in the [Azure AD B2C UserVoice forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c).

Comment: Looks like you can do it via the graph api now [When changing an Azure B2C email adress, do I need to change the UPN as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645576/when-changing-an-azure-b2c-email-adress-do-i-need-to-change-the-upn-as-well)